# How to have a tab create a functional UI - Static reference to a non-static method

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar

I am designing a action bar tab interface using the tutorial on android ([FragmentTabs.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html)) and I am running into problems when I try to track the fragments that I switch to display within the tab. (I switch tabs via buttons and using the onClick in the layout file to find a method in the main activity)

In this part of the code within TabListener the fragment is updated:

```
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
```

Which has its arguments passed to from:

```
bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
            .setText("MMC/Data Commands")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<MMCFragment>(
                    this, "MMCFragment", MMCFragment.class)));
```

So, what happens is I try to get "mFragment" updated when a user presses a button on the view created within the tab. If I don't update it when the user switches tabs:

```
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }
```

it detaches mFragment, which is the original fragment passed to it when the tab has been created i.e. the fragment with tag "MMCFragment", which is a problem when the view has been switched to a different fragment.
So I made a method within TabListener:

```
public void updateMfrag(String tag){
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
```

but I get an error when I call it from outside the method because I make a static reference to a non-static method. How can I fix this? Or is there a better way to navigate views within a tab?

Comment: Can you post all code, not just snippets? And can you post the stack trace?